# fill a listview with  custom layout items 

Tags: android, view, progress-bar

i have an arraylist of data ( bluetooth devices ) and i want to list those devices in a list,
For this i have made a customized view (item.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/images" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_margin="10dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Composed of an imageview and a textview, so i can put the name of the device and a standard image int the list, here is the main.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the progress bar is for the scanning operation in the beginning of the activity.

any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listview can support different layouts(views) and can be built dynamically. This is done through a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

you need listview to hold those data in the list. in your main layout i cant see any listview. after taking list view you need to define adapter for that listview and use this adapter in your listview.

Hope this will help you